# python webbrowser leaves the shell open

Tags: python, shell, python-webbrowser

I made a small python programm with the webbrowser modle wich is supposed to open a new tab in the browser and go to http://kivy.org/#home.
I ran it with the linux shell and it worked fine, a new tab was opened and it went to http://kivy.org/#home.
But when I wanted to run it again, I realised that I got the error message:

```
(process:9606): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

And it looked like the Program was not closed because I could not type in anything, so I had to close it with `^C` 
Here is my source code:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://kivy.org/#home')
```

Comment: For us novice noobs, could you paste a link to the source of `webbrowser`? :)

Comment: @Torxed python standard library. just import it

Comment: It works fine on Windows 8  console.

Comment: Is that just an error message your browser is emitting in the background? What happens if you just hit Enter? Do you get a shell prompt? You script works fine for me on Linux.

Comment: @glenn jackman I get the error massage in the my linux shell

Comment: @Gilgamesch
You may want to have a look at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672671

Comment: @Gilgamesch, so, when you see the error, what happens if you hit enter?

Comment: @glenn jackman when I click Enter, everything is normal again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a built-in function called `quit()`, no import required, it will terminate the script in your shell.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://kivy.org/#home')
quit()
```